# Redirect URL using HTML form parameters using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML page which has form parameters that are hidden and I would like to redirect to another URL as soon as I click on the HTML page passing the same parameters. I am not able to redirect currently with the id and password.

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
function runReport()
{
document.mstr.submit();
}
</script>
<form name = "mstr" action = "www.xyz.com" method = "post">
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="xyz" />
<input type="hidden" name="pwd" value="xyz" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are looking for a little more? Do you want to redirect when ever someone clicks anywhere on the page? or only when they submit the form? What is the url structure you are trying to redirect too? `www.xyc.com/uid/pws`?

Comment: I have edited my post with the HTMl code.. Please check again.. I would like to double click on this HTML page and it should redirect the URL accepting the ID and password from the form for logging in but not displaying in the URL.

Comment: can you use the jQuery library or does it have to be straight javascript?

Comment: yes i can.. can you pls guide me what to use?

Comment: Check out the answer I added for how to do this using jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect in a few different ways. One is to `window.location`:

```
window.location = 'newPage.php';
```

You can append `$_GET[]` variables onto the end of the url.

---

If you want to post variables, you need to use a form:

```
<form id="hiddenForm" action="newPage.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="..."/>
   <input type="hidden" name="pwd" value="..."/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("hiddenForm").submit();
```

And then on newPage.php, you can access your variables with `$_POST[]`:

```
$uid = $_POST["uid"];
$pwd = $_POST["pwd"];
```

Comment: Thanks David for your response. I have edited my post with the HTML code i am trying to use. I tried what you mentioned but it does not work.

Comment: `parent` is _meant_ to refer to the parent of an iframe. `window.location` would be cleaner.

Comment: You have to tell me what part is not working for you. Is the form posting? Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: @sabof noted and fixed.

Comment: can you please let me know how can i add POST variables.. as the URL that i want to redirect is a http link.. I do not get any error as such by using document.getElementById("hiddenForm").submit(); Nothing happens when i click on HTML page.

Comment: @user3438791 You would add post variables by using inputs in the form. You would bind the submit function to the onClick event of the HTML page, like `<body onclick="document.getElementById('hiddenForm').submit();">`

Answer (score 0):

Using the jquery listener for double click(dblclick) you can then bind to that and submit your from when ever someone double clicks in your document. This will post the data that is in the form to the action url of the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>XYZ</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $(document).on('dblclick', function() {
                    $('form[name="mstr"]').submit();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <form name="mstr" action="http://www.xyz.com" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="xyz" />
            <input type="hidden" name="pwd" value="xyz" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

If your action is on a different url then the one you are on now you will either need to have `http://` or `https://` You can also just use `//www.your-domain.com` and this will mimic the current site. So if you are currently in `http` it will use that, same for `https`

Comment: I tried with the above code but nothing happens.. It just shows me blank page.

Comment: right, you have no content on the page. Is there suppose to be stuff there?

Comment: I just want to route to the URL "http://www.xyz.com" that is being specified in action

Comment: thats what happens, when you load this page, double click anywhere in it. It will take you to that url

Comment: Unfortunately, its not taking me to that URL. as soon as i open HTML page it shows me blank page and URL is not routed.

Comment: You have to double click in the page for it to take you to that page. Are you trying to automatically take you to the form location once the page loads?